# Selectable nested collapsible list in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've spent a few days on this and trying to build out this component but it simply doesn't want to exist. I'm trying to create a mobile-friendly tree-like structure where there is a list of collapsibles which, in turn, contain more collapsible, and I can select any item at any level. I've been able to build out different components separately but not combine them together. So far I have:

- [Nested list of collapsibles](http://jsfiddle.net/marsguy/Lyhb9p4z/3/) ([but no way to select collapsible headers](http://jsfiddle.net/marsguy/cyp20mz0/3/))
- [Selectable collapsible headers](http://jsfiddle.net/marsguy/BxFsC/24/) ([but no way to nest aesthetically](http://jsfiddle.net/marsguy/UV7Xn/19/))
- [Filtering through a list+sublists (but shows a box for each level) [less important, I'll just make my own search]](http://jsfiddle.net/marsguy/Lyhb9p4z/4/)

Ideally I just need to know what is the last item a user clicked on - whether a header of a collapsible or just a leaf list element. However I also need to present that information to the user. I've tried changing the button theme on-the-fly, but that messes up the formatting for some reason. I've tried adding radio buttons, but I can't seem to make them selectable/unselectable from the collapsible header.

Each successfully implemented isolated component is in the list above, with the part that filed in parenthesis.

### Part 1: Nested list of collapsibles

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="left" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false">
        <h3>Birds</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="false" data-inset="true" data-corners="false">
            <li>Condor</li>
            <li><a href="#">Eagle</a>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="left" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false">
                <h2>Sublist</h2>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="false" data-inset="true" data-corners="false">
                    <li>Sublistitem 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Part 2: Selectable collapsible headers

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="false" data-filter="true" data-split-icon="check">
    <li> <a style="padding: 0;">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" style="margin: -.7em 0 -.7em 0;">
            <h2>Mark Twain</h2>
            <div>
                 <p>More info</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </a>
     <a data-theme="c" class="checkButton" id="1"></a>
 </li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but no way to select collapsible headers"?